# Searching for strings in InnoDB table column

Tags: mysql

My events table runs on InnoDB and I would like my website user to be able to search for words that appear in the events headline and description. In my events table I have two columns "headline" and "description".

If for example my user wants to look for "football": Is there any way to write an SQL query that successfully performs this query on an InnoDB table? Do I HAVE TO switch to MyISAM?

I do not want to switch to MyISAM because then I cannot set foreign keys.

Comment: Use LIKE or even fulltetxt search you are are on 5.6>

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a OR statement in your where clause, and as Mihai suggested use LIKE with wildcards '%' on either side of the search word.

If in PHP, once you capture your search word from the user, sanitize it for security, then place it in a query like below:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, headline, description FROM mytable a WHERE (a.headline LIKE '%".$sanitized_searchword."%' OR a.description LIKE '%".$sanatized_searchword."%')";
```